# How to InsertBefore or InsertAfter the first element that has a specific element inside of it?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have some HTML (which I have no control over) coming from a DB and it contains lots of text and images. I need to insert a particular element before or after the first `<a>` tag that has an `<img>` tag inside it.

Here is an example of the HTML:

```
<section class="main">
<p>Nokia 8 4GB RAM 64GB Dual Sim Phone</p>
<p>The Nokia 8 undergoes a rigorous 40-stage process of machining, anodizing and polishing to ensure its distinctive design pairs flawlessly with the polished aluminium unibody.</p>
<p>The ultimate in seamless unibody construction, Nokia 8 is designed to nestle perfectly in the palm of your hand.</p>
<a href="https://www.nokia.com">
<img src="https://cdn2.gsmarena.com/vv/bigpic/nokia-8-.jpg" />
</a>
<p>We offer 14 days money back guarantee in case of a change of mind. </p>
</section>
<div class="movethisdiv">I want to move this content</div>
```

This is as far as I can get to moving the `div` before the `img` element but obviously it will never work because the img is wrapped in an anchor tag. So how would I get jQuery to insert the `div` before the first anchor element that has an image inside of it?

```
$(".movethisdiv").insertBefore( $("section.main").find("a > img").first());
```

The above will insert the `div` before the `img` tag only, but within the `a` element. I want it to insertBefore the `a` element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `.parent()` after `.first()` so something like this:

```js
$(".movethisdiv").insertBefore($("section.main").find("a > img").first().parent());
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a filter:

```js
$('.movethisdiv').insertBefore(
  $("section.main").find('a').filter(function() { // get all anchors in main
    return $(this).children('img').length;        // filter out anchors with an image
  }).first());                                    // get the first one
```

```css
.movethisdiv {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="main">
  <p>Nokia 8 4GB RAM 64GB Dual Sim Phone</p>
  <a href="#">a test link</a>
  <p>The Nokia 8 undergoes a rigorous 40-stage process of machining, anodizing and polishing to ensure its distinctive design pairs flawlessly with the polished aluminium unibody.</p>
  <p>The ultimate in seamless unibody construction, Nokia 8 is designed to nestle perfectly in the palm of your hand.</p>
  <a href="https://www.nokia.com">
    <img src="https://cdn2.gsmarena.com/vv/bigpic/nokia-8-.jpg" />
  </a>
  <p>We offer 14 days money back guarantee in case of a change of mind. </p>
</section>
<div class="movethisdiv">I want to move this content</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

use [`.first()`](https://api.jquery.com/first/) and [`.parent()`](https://api.jquery.com/parent/) method here is example

```js
$("a").find('img').first($(".movethisdiv").insertBefore($("section.main > a img:first").parent()));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="main">
<p>Nokia 8 4GB RAM 64GB Dual Sim Phone</p>
<p>The Nokia 8 undergoes a rigorous 40-stage process of machining, anodizing and polishing to ensure its distinctive design pairs flawlessly with the polished aluminium unibody.</p>
<p>The ultimate in seamless unibody construction, Nokia 8 is designed to nestle perfectly in the palm of your hand.</p>
<a href="https://www.nokia.com">
<img src="https://cdn2.gsmarena.com/vv/bigpic/nokia-8-.jpg" />
</a>
<p>We offer 14 days money back guarantee in case of a change of mind. </p>
</section>
<div class="movethisdiv">I want to move this content</div>
```

Comment: Not exactly. The div is still within the anchor element and so now has been hyperlinked to the Nokia site. I need the div to go BEFORE the anchor element that has an image inside of it

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this.

Find all `img` that are inside an `a` , select first one, and select it's parent.

Then insert the div before that parent

```js
let  firstAnchor = $("a img").first().parent()


$(".movethisdiv").insertBefore(firstAnchor)
```

```css
.movethisdiv {
color:red;
font-size:20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="main">
  <p>Nokia 8 4GB RAM 64GB Dual Sim Phone</p>
  <p>The Nokia 8 undergoes a rigorous 40-stage process of machining, anodizing and polishing to ensure its distinctive design pairs flawlessly with the polished aluminium unibody.</p>
  <p>The ultimate in seamless unibody construction, Nokia 8 is designed to nestle perfectly in the palm of your hand.</p>
  <a href="https://www.nokia.com">
<img src="https://cdn2.gsmarena.com/vv/bigpic/nokia-8-.jpg" />
</a>
  <p>We offer 14 days money back guarantee in case of a change of mind. </p>
  <a href="https://www.nokia.com">
<img src="https://cdn2.gsmarena.com/vv/bigpic/nokia-8-.jpg" />
</a>
  <a href="https://www.nokia.com">
<img src="https://cdn2.gsmarena.com/vv/bigpic/nokia-8-.jpg" />
</a>
  <a href="https://www.nokia.com">
<img src="https://cdn2.gsmarena.com/vv/bigpic/nokia-8-.jpg" />
</a>
</section>
<div class="movethisdiv">I want to move this content</div>
```